# Python: for loop outside of while loop not working as expected

Tags: python

I want to get how many attempts have been made before a random value between 0 and 10 is greater than 8. I have the following code which works correctly:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=1)
attempt = 1

while(x < 8):
    attempt = attempt + 1
    x = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=1)
```

However, now I want to get the number of attempts before x was greater than 8 for the fourth time. To do this, I placed the for loop just before the while loop which becomes like this:

```
for i in range(0,4):
    while(x < 8):
        attempt = attempt + 1
        x = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=1)
```

However, this is not working as I intended it to be. Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: *this is not working as I intended it to be* is hardly any useful information. What did you intend it to be? What did it actually do?

Comment: You never reset `x` so once `x > 8` it stays that way for every interation of your for loop. Put `x=0` between your `for` and your `while`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to get the total number of attempts needed to obtain a random number `8` in 4 consecutive trails. Try this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def fun():
...     x = np.random.uniform(0,10,1)
...     attempt = 1
...     while x<8:
...             attempt += 1
...             x = np.random.uniform(0,10,1)
...     return attempt 
>>> for i in range(0,4):
...     print("Trial" , i , "took" , fun(), "Attempts")
```

Output:

```
Trial 0 took 1 Attempts
Trial 1 took 1 Attempts
Trial 2 took 8 Attempts
Trial 3 took 3 Attempts
```

Comment: Can you also explain why @Beatrice's solution didn't work?

Comment: @DhruvJoshi, Beatrice's code works perfectly fine, but the only issue was that it wasn't generating the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not resetting your x value. So once the variable is set to a value greater than 8, you code will not enter the while loop again. You need to set x = 0 before the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your code to

```
for i in range(0,4):
    x = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=1)
    while(x < 8):
        attempt = attempt + 1
        x = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=1)
```

This would reset x before it enters into the `while` loop. Without this statement, your the control enters into the while loop only once.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this.  The below should work...

```
import numpy as np

successes = 0
rolls = 0
while (successes < 4):
    x = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=1)
    rolls += 1
    if x > 8:
        successes += 1

print(rolls)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a `for loop` case.
Try this:

```
while x < 8 and i <= 4:
    x = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=1)
    if x>8:
        i+=1
        x=np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=1)
        attempt = 1
    print(attempt, x)
    attempt = attempt + 1
```

Comment: This won't work.  OP needs 4 rolls above 8 not 4 rolls in total.